# How to use stretched-link bootstrap class and keep :hover behavior on card itself?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap product card. I want to be able to access the product details either by clicking on the card itself or by clicking on the product name. I found the `stretched-link` Bootstrap's class so I added this. Now the problem is that I lost all of the `:hover` behaviors on different elements on the card.

My card :

```
<div class="col mb-4">
    <div class="product-card">
        <img src="../asset/images/golden-chain-purse.jpg" class="card-img-top product-img" alt="...">
        <p class="product-price">{{ product.price }}
            €
        </p>
        <a class="etsy-button" href="{{ product.etsyLink }}" target="_blank">Buy on Etsy &copy</a>
        <a class="product-details-link stretched-link" href="{{ path('product_details', {product_id: product.id }) }}"></a>
    </div>
    <a class="product-details-link" href="{{ path('product_details', {product_id: product.id }) }}">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{ product.name }}</h5>
    </a>
</div>
```

the different: hover of my card

```
.product-card:hover img {
    filter: blur(3px);
}

.product-card:hover :not(img) {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: .5s;
}

.etsy-button:hover {
    background-color: rgba(238, 182, 191, 0.637);
    padding: 0.4em 0.6em;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: 0.3em;
}

.product-details-link:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Its the problem of `z-index`, you can solve it by

```
.<that_class_that_not_show_your_hover> {
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
}
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
.etsy-button {
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>
  .product-card:hover img {
    filter: blur(3px);
  }
  
  .product-card:hover :not(img) {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: .5s;
  }
  
  .etsy-button:hover {
    background-color: rgba(238, 182, 191, 0.637);
    padding: 0.4em 0.6em;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: 0.3em;
  }
  
  .product-details-link:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  .etsy-button {
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
  }
</style>


<div class="col mb-4">
  <div class="product-card">
    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/381/200/300.jpg" class="card-img-top product-img" alt="...">
    <p class="product-price">{{ product.price }} €
    </p>
    <a class="etsy-button" href="https://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">Buy on Etsy &copy</a>
    <a class="product-details-link stretched-link" href="https://google.com"></a>
  </div>
  <a class="product-details-link" href="{{ path('product_details', {product_id: product.id }) }}">
    <h5 class="card-title">{{ product.name }}</h5>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's a bit better, but now I have the hover effect on the image only when I'm on the etsy-button. But when the image is blurred, the stretched-link doesn't work anymore... Do you have any idea?

Comment: I don't face any problem like that in my machine, let me give you an example, check updated answer

Comment: The problem I have is caused by the fact that my etsy button and product.price are on the image and not bellow..